# Google Analytics API return multiple landing pages data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Can anyone help me out with this?  I need to use the GA api to return data of multiple landing pages. Data such as page views, bounce rate, avg time on page, etc.

So far I've managed to return the data for 1 page when this is set in the filters. Is there anyway to do this for multiple pages in 1 request?

```
// Google API Library
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
    g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
    js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));


gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

    var CLIENT_ID = clientID
    var VIEW_ID = viewID;

    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'auth-button',
        clientid: CLIENT_ID
    });


    var query = {
        ids: VIEW_ID,
        metrics: 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:bounceRate',
        dimensions: 'ga:date',
        filters: 'ga:pagePath=@page1' //<-- page name to search for
    }

    var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({ query });
    report.on('success', function(response) {
        console.log(response);      
    });

    report.execute();
});
```

Comment: If this is about landing pages you probably want to filter by ga:landingPagePath, not ga:pagePath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `,ga:pagePath=@page2` in filters for get also the data of the second page and add `ga:pagePath` in dimensions for separate the two pages in the result.

```
        var query = {
            ids: VIEW_ID,
            metrics: 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:bounceRate',
            dimensions: 'ga:date,ga:pagePath',
            filters: 'ga:pagePath=@page1,ga:pagePath=@page2' //<-- page name to search for
        }
```

Comment: I did try that but looking in the console at “totalsForAllResults” the results get combined.

If page1 has 10 pageViews and page2 has 5 pageViews it’ll return as 15.  I want to separate the data returned to individual pages.

Comment: sorry, pagePath is a dimensions, not a metric. Try now, I've tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For new [GA v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/FilterExpression), you can pass page paths as array to `inListFilter` under `dimensionFilter`

```js
const response = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${`xxxxxxxx`}`,
      dateRanges: [
        {
          startDate: startDate,
          endDate: "today",
        },
      ],
      dimensionFilter: {
        filter: {
          inListFilter: {
            values: pagePathsArr,
          },
          fieldName: "pagePath",
          // stringFilter: {
          //   value: slug,
          // },
        },
      },
      dimensions: [
        {
          name: "pagePath",
        },
      ],
      metrics: [
        {
          name: "screenPageViews",
        },
      ],
    });
```